Probability of matrix over $\Bbb{F}_2$ having rank $j$
Let $j$ be a fixed odd positive integer.
Let $P(n|j)$ denote the probability that a uniformly random $n\times n$ alternating matrix over $\Bbb{F}_2$(namely, symmetric matrix with diagonal entries all zero) has rank $n-j$. I want to prove that $P(2n\mid j)+P(2n+1|j)$ converges to a positive value as $n$ approaches infinity.
If $P(2n+1|j)$ converges to a positive value, we know limit of $P(2n\mid j)+P(2n+1|j)$ must be positive because:
$P(n|j)\neq 0$ if and only if $j \equiv n \pmod{2}$.
(See the top of page 4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.05674.)
Direct calculation of these probabilities seems intractable. How can I show the existence of this limit ?
In other words, based on this discussion about parity, this leads to the question: for large matrices, does the probability of achieving 'nearly' maximum rank converge to a certain constant value rather than collapsing to zero?

The canonical form of a matrix of rank $i$ maybe useful here.
